# R returns row sum as zero in case of all NA

Tags: r, data.table

Is there anyway to avoid 0 as result in case all rows are NA while computing rowSum using na.rm =T

in below example row sum is zero in case all rows are NA but I need NA in results. I cant skip using na.rm = T because other cases may have some NA.
and I am specifically looking for data table solution.

```
`df <- data.table::fread("X Y
2   26
3   NA
0 0
NA  NA
4   5
", header = TRUE)
df[,Sum:=rowSums(.SD,na.rm = T), .SDcols = names(df)]`
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg for pointing out my previous idea was wrong. I believe this should work (and would preserve cases were sum = 0, but not all row values are NA): `df[,Sum:={rs = rowSums(.SD,na.rm = T); ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == ncol(.SD), NA, rs)}, .SDcols = names(df)]`

Comment: It's my bad.. I should have provided a sample data row where all rows are zero

Comment: You could do something like `df[, Sum := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) * rowSums(!is.na(.SD)), .SDcols = names(df)]` and get `NaN` instead of `NA`. But I'm not sure how efficient/readable it is.

Comment: Maybe somthing like `df[, Sum:= ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.SD[, 1:length(.SD)])) == length(.SD), NA,
                   rowSums(.SD[, 1:length(.SD)], na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = names(df)]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do this. My input:

```
df[, Sum:= rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA ^ (rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0)]
```

Will return:

```
    X  Y Sum
1:  2 26  28
2:  3 NA   3
3:  0  0   0
4: NA NA  NA
5:  4  5   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, call the rowSums function only on the rows that you don't want to be NA. The assign by reference call will fill the rest with NA:

```
df[, .SD
   ][Reduce('*', lapply(df, is.na)) == 0, sum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm=T)
   ][]

    X  Y sum
1:  2 26  28
2:  3 NA   3
3:  0  0   0
4: NA NA  NA
5:  4  5   9
```